# Unable to authenticate with Confluence server for Sphinx documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, confluence, documentation-generation

I am using sphinx for building documentation in confluence.I am able to make html file using sphinx. But when I am trying to connect confluence using the "make confluence" command it's throwing an error

I checked by changing the confluence password and checked using API token still getting the error and unable to connect with confluence.

Ref link-
https://github.com/Shravankumarhiregoudar/sphinxDocumentation

conf.py file:

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/4px/sphinx/scripts/')


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'sites'
copyright = '2021, divyank'
author = 'divyank'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder'
]
confluence_publish = True
confluence_space_name = 'Documentation'
##confluence_ask_password = True
#confluence_parent_name = 'API Documentation'
# (for Confluence Cloud)
confluence_server_url = 'https://<....>.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces'
confluence_server_user = '<....>'
confluence_server_pass = '<.......>'
# (or, for Confluence Server)
#confluence_server_url = 'https://intranet-wiki.example.com/'
#confluence_server_user = 'myawesomeuser'

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns=[]


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'default'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

latex_elements = {
# The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    'papersize': 'letterpaper',
# The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    'pointsize': '10pt',
# Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    'preamble': '',
# Latex figure (float) alignment
    'figure_align': 'htbp',
}
```

Error:

```
WARNING: normalizing confluence url from https://<......>.atlassian.net/wiki/ to https://<.......>.atlassian.net/wiki/

sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder error:
---
Unable to authenticate with the Confluence server.

Ensure your username and password are correct. If your username and password is correct, you may need to unlock your Confluence account be re-logging in with your browser or asking your Confluence administrator for help.
---

make: *** [confluence] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue using API token in the confluence password field in conf.py file.

How to generate API token-
[Manage API tokens for your Atlassian account](https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/)

Ref link-

[Unable to authenticate with the Confluence server using sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Unable-to-authenticate-with-the-Confluence-server-using/qaq-p/1790274)